# Mostly portable 128 by 64 bit division

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, integer, bitwise

I wrote this out of curiosity. It is based on the theory behind Knuth's Algorithm D and is intended to emulate the behavior of the x86 `div` instruction (though the result is truncated instead of raising an exception for overflow).

I am primarily interested in correctness (it seems to work correctly), and have not yet compared performance with anything simpler.

Two's complement hardware is assumed.

```
uint64_t div(uint64_t a_lo, uint64_t a_hi, uint64_t b, uint64_t &r)
{
    uint64_t p_lo;
    uint64_t p_hi;
    uint64_t q = 0;

    auto r_hi = a_hi;
    auto r_lo = a_lo;

    int s = 0;
    if(0 == (b >> 63)){

        // Normalize so quotient estimates are
        // no more than 2 in error.

        // Note: If any bits get shifted out of
        // r_hi at this point, the result would
        // overflow.

        s = 63 - bsr(b);
        const auto t = 64 - s;

        b <<= s;
        r_hi = (r_hi << s)|(r_lo >> t);
        r_lo <<= s;
    }

    const auto b_hi = b >> 32;

    /*
    The first full-by-half division places b
    across r_hi and r_lo, making the reduction
    step a little complicated.

    To make this easier, u_hi and u_lo will hold
    a shifted image of the remainder.

    [u_hi||    ][u_lo||    ]
          [r_hi||    ][r_lo||    ]
                [ b  ||    ]
    [p_hi||    ][p_lo||    ]
                  |
                  V
                [q_hi||    ]
    */

    auto q_hat = r_hi / b_hi;

    p_lo = mul(b, q_hat, p_hi);

    const auto u_hi = r_hi >> 32;
    const auto u_lo = (r_hi << 32)|(r_lo >> 32);

    // r -= b*q_hat
    //
    // At most 2 iterations of this...
    while(
        (p_hi > u_hi) ||
        ((p_hi == u_hi) && (p_lo > u_lo))
        )
    {
        if(p_lo < b){
            --p_hi;
        }
        p_lo -= b;
        --q_hat;
    }

    auto w_lo = (p_lo << 32);
    auto w_hi = (p_hi << 32)|(p_lo >> 32);

    if(w_lo > r_lo){
        ++w_hi;
    }

    r_lo -= w_lo;
    r_hi -= w_hi;

    q = q_hat << 32;

    /*
    The lower half of the quotient is easier,
    as b is now aligned with r_lo.

          |r_hi][r_lo||    ]
                [ b  ||    ]
    [p_hi||    ][p_lo||    ]
                        |
                        V
                [q_hi||q_lo]
    */

    q_hat = ((r_hi << 32)|(r_lo >> 32)) / b_hi;

    p_lo = mul(b, q_hat, p_hi);

    // r -= b*q_hat
    //
    // ...and at most 2 iterations of this.
    while(
        (p_hi > r_hi) ||
        ((p_hi == r_hi) && (p_lo > r_lo))
        )
    {
        if(p_lo < b){
            --p_hi;
        }
        p_lo -= b;
        --q_hat;
    }

    r_lo -= p_lo;

    q |= q_hat;

    r = r_lo >> s;

    return q;
}
```

For convenience, below are the `bsr` and `mul` functions used above. The `bsr` routine comes from [this useful site](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html):

```
int bsr(uint64_t x)
{
    uint64_t y;
    uint64_t r;

    r = (x > 0xFFFFFFFF) << 5; x >>= r;
    y = (x > 0xFFFF    ) << 4; x >>= y; r |= y;
    y = (x > 0xFF      ) << 3; x >>= y; r |= y;
    y = (x > 0xF       ) << 2; x >>= y; r |= y;
    y = (x > 0x3       ) << 1; x >>= y; r |= y;

    return static_cast<int>(r | (x >> 1));
}

uint64_t mul(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t &y)
{
    auto a_lo = a & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF;
    auto a_hi = a >> 32;

    auto b_lo = b & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF;
    auto b_hi = b >> 32;

    auto c0 = a_lo * b_lo;
    auto c1 = a_hi * b_lo;
    auto c2 = a_hi * b_hi;

    auto u1 = c1 + (a_lo * b_hi);
    if(u1 < c1){
        c2 += 1LL << 32;
    }

    auto u0 = c0 + (u1 << 32);
    if(u0 < c0){
        ++c2;
    }

    y = c2 + (u1 >> 32);

    return u0;
}
```

Comment: Is the answer received useful? If so, consider upvoting/selecting it. If not, try leaving a comment to the user or ask for clarification about his points.

Comment: Almost forgot this place existed :| A point has been given! Not sure the Q&A format really applies to code review (not to this one, anyway). If nothing happens in a week, it will be selected as the answer.

Comment: I see one problem right away: you're assuming that the quotient will fit in a 64-bit result. What if the dividend is more than 64 bits and the divisor is 1?

Comment: @EdwardFalk The result is undefined. Generally, `div` is used for the double-by-single word divide required for computing multiple precision quotients. Knuth's explanation is better than what I can fit in a comment, though in short, the arguments are normalized so their "limbs", as provided to the primitive divide, should never produce an undefined result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original code seemed too complicated for this so I set out to write a simpler version. Should be fairly portable too, and fast as it is just bit shifts and subtraction.

(It works similarly to how one would accomplish division in assembly language on a processor without hardware division.)

```
// 128-bit / 64-bit unsigned divide

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
  // numerator
  uint64_t a_lo = 1234567;
  uint64_t a_hi = 0;

  // denominator
  uint64_t b = 10;

  // quotient
  uint64_t q = a_lo << 1;

  // remainder
  uint64_t rem = a_hi;

  uint64_t carry = a_lo >> 63;
  uint64_t temp_carry = 0;
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < 64; i++)
  {
    temp_carry = rem >> 63;
    rem <<= 1;
    rem |= carry;
    carry = temp_carry;

    if(carry == 0)
    {
      if(rem >= b)
      {
        carry = 1;
      }
      else
      {
        temp_carry = q >> 63;
        q <<= 1;
        q |= carry;
        carry = temp_carry;
        continue;
      }
    }

    rem -= b;
    rem -= (1 - carry);
    carry = 1;
    temp_carry = q >> 63;
    q <<= 1;
    q |= carry;
    carry = temp_carry;
  }

  printf("quotient = %llu\n", (long long unsigned int)q);
  printf("remainder = %llu\n", (long long unsigned int)rem);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The test case for this code has only very small values. I replaced a_hi, a_lo, and b with these values: 0xc3ac542864f652f8, 0xa3ccac1832952398,0x5267b85f8a42fc20. This asks for the division 260094241160506081433645566617850291096 / 5937917354192337952. The program gives quotient 15148923828744002542 and remainder 171728852755111384. These values are wrong. But they would be the right values if a_hi was 0x43ac542864f652f8. Perhaps the highest bit of the numerator is not being handled properly.

Comment: Thanks for revealing the flaw. I don't have time to sort it out so will let your post stand as a warning for now.

Answer (score 1):

Only the second solution is correct. The first approach fails for some cases, specially for numerators close to 128 bits limits.

Comment: Could you expand on this a bit? What cases does the first fail for and why? I feel like there's a good answer in here just waiting to come out.